# need to embed a flex slider in an image field

Tags: javascript

Flex slider is working fine on the site.
Made an example and it works fine.
I have an image field in a content type and set its display to flexslider full.
I can upload only one image (although it is set to unlimited), how can I embed the flexslider carousel in that image field?

Comment: if it is set to unlimited then it must allow you to upload multiple images.

Comment: I am embarrassed for asking this question.  Of course, if it set to unlimited you will not find restrictions.  What happened is that I cloned the site, it was originally set to unlimited, and did not realize that settings had changed. Thank you.